# Android: How to make Spinner show other sqlite values in EditText

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hello I'm new in programming android and i have question about android studio..

I have a database with 3 columns is "no", ""namamakanan" and "kalori". And I have input data in table:
(no, namamakanan, kalori) values ('1', 'nasi uduk', '343'), ('2', 'nasi goreng', '1046')

My question is, How to showing "kalori" data from database to EditText etpagilaukkcal1 when i choose "nasi goreng" from spinner?

Example when i choose "nasi goreng", etpagilauk1kcal is "1046" or "nasi uduk", etpagilauk1kcal is "343".

Thank you..

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BuatJadwalDiet extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinnerpagilauk1, spinnerpagilauk2;
    EditText etpagilauk1kcal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buat_jadwal_diet);

        // Spinner element
        spinnerpagilauk1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerpagilauk1);
        spinnerpagilauk2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerpagilauk2);
        etpagilauk1kcal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpagilauk1kcal);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinnerpagilauk1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinnerpagilauk2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Loading spinner data from database
        loadSpinnerData();

    }

    private void loadSpinnerData() {

        // database handler
        DataHelperMakanan db = new DataHelperMakanan(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down element
        List<String> label = db.getAllNames();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, label);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerpagilauk1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerpagilauk2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

        // On selecting a spinner item
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Kamu Memilih: " + label,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And this is my DataHelper

```
public class DataHelperMakanan extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "nutrizimakanan.db";

  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  public DataHelperMakanan(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String makanan = "create table makanan(no integer primary key, namamakanan text null, kalori integer);";
    Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + makanan);
    db.execSQL(makanan);
    makanan = "INSERT INTO makanan (no, namamakanan, kalori) VALUES ('1', 'Nasi Uduk', '494');";

    db.execSQL(makanan);



  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }

  public List<String> getAllNames(){
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM makanan";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            names.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning names
    return names;
}
```

Comment: use  ctrl+k to format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a query to the DatabaseHelper that returns the kalon column based upon the value of the namamakanan column.

e.g.

```
    public String getKalonFromNamamakanan(String namamakanan) {

        String rv = "Unknown";
        String[] columns = { "kalon" };
        String whereclause = "namamakanan=?";
        String[] whereargs = { namamakanan };
        Cursor csr = db.query("yourtable",columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if(csr.getCount() > 0) {
            csr.moveToFirst();
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("kalon"));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
```

You could then get the kalon based upon the namamakanan column using something like.

```
    etpagilauk1kcal.setText(db.getKalonFromNamamakanan(label));
```

in your `onItemSelected` method. Note this assumes that the namamakanan will be unique and that **db** will be the SQLiteDatabase (*i.e you may have to add `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` or `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();`, depending upon how `DataHelperMakanan` is coded*)

### How the code could be to use separate/individual Listeners (added as per comment)

Instead of

```
    spinnerpagilauk1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerpagilauk2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You could have :-

```
    spinnerpagilauk1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view,
                                   int i,
                                   long l) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            etpagilauk1kcal.setText(db.getKalonFromNamamakanan(label));
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    spinnerpagilauk2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view,
                                   int i,
                                   long l) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            etpagilauk1kca2.setText(db.getKalonFromNamamakanan(label));
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: hello, thank you for answer my question.. I try using this code, but etpagilauk1kcal showing "Unknown" not a data from my database.

Comment: Sorry, instead of `String whereclause = "kalon=?";`, it should be `String whereclause = "namamakanan=?";`. The answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: hello, I'm trying your new code and success but when i make next EditText "etpagilauk2kcal". this edittext value is similiar like "etpagilauk1kcal"

Comment: The reason is that both listeners are the same listener and thus set the text for the 1 EditText. I've edited the answer to include code for individual listeners.